# Nested divs with background images - browser compatibility issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap framework.In my web app I am using two divs both having background images.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="abc">
 <div class=" container abcd">
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
    <p style="color:white">abc</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS code

```
.abc{
  position:relative;
  background-image:url("http://i57.tinypic.com/1zl3a0z.png");
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
.abcd{
  width:200px; 
  background-image:url(" http://i62.tinypic.com/347b4vs.png ");
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #000;  
  border: 6px solid white;
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
 }
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cptehowa/2/)

Depending upon size of screen, the inner div (for which width-attribute is mentioned) appears different.On 15" screen, inner div touches the cup in outer image whereas on 13" screen it does not touch the cup. I want the page to appear same on all the browsers. Is there any other approach than using two divs? I think the inner div's width is creating issues depending upon different screen sizes.

Comment: The problem is the outer image scales with size but the inner one doesn't. Could you get away with a percentage width instead of fixed? Say `width: 40%;` instead of `width: 200px;`?

Comment: @DavidG I think this should do for him..

Comment: @DavidG : It worked. Thanks for your help ! Can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it !

Comment: @DavidG : There is a problem with that solution. When I zoom in/out , the contents inside the inner div get scattered

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom in"?

Comment: I mean, when I "zoom in" my browser, the content inside the div behave unsual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the outer image scales with size but the inner one doesn't. You could fix this by using a percentage width instead of fixed. For example `width: 40%;` instead of `width: 200px;`:

```
.abcd {
    width: 40%; 
    background-image: url(" http://i62.tinypic.com/347b4vs.png ");
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #000;  
    border: 6px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

And an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cptehowa/3/

Answer (score 0):

Update css

```css
.abc {
    position:relative;
    background-image:url("http://i57.tinypic.com/1zl3a0z.png");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-height:500px;
}
.abcd{
    width:200px; background-image:url(" http://i62.tinypic.com/347b4vs.png ");box-shadow: 0 0 25px #000;  border: 6px solid white;position:relative;top:5px;
}
```

Comment: you have used background cover so you can set height or min-height in parent div.

Comment: the problem is with the inner div. It scales more on devices with bigger screen.

Comment: Of course, it will sclaed propertionally so you can set different height within media breakpoint